# Plotly: How to only show vertical and horizontal line (crosshair) as hoverinfo?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to plot a chart with two subplots in plotly dash. My entire chart looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv').iloc[:60]
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, row_heights=[0.8, 0.2], vertical_spacing=0)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(open=df['AAPL.Open'], high=df['AAPL.High'], low=df['AAPL.Low'], close=df['AAPL.Close'],
                             increasing_line_color='#0384fc', decreasing_line_color='#e8482c', name='AAPL'), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=np.random.randint(20, 40, len(df)), marker_color='#fae823', name='VO', hovertemplate=[]), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'paper_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'legend_orientation': "h"},
                  legend=dict(y=1, x=0),
                  font=dict(color='#dedddc'), dragmode='pan', hovermode='x unified',
                  margin=dict(b=20, t=0, l=0, r=40))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, rangeslider_visible=False, showticklabels=False,
                 showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='data', showline=False, spikedash='solid')

fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
fig.update_traces(xaxis='x', hoverinfo='none')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='chart', figure=fig, config={'displayModeBar': False}))])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

What I need is a so called crosshair that is common in trading charts. Basically it consists of two lines that are connected to x and y axes and moves with cursor. This is a screenshot from tradingview.com charts:
[image]

However in my chart there is a little icon that appears when the cursor is on candlesticks:
[image]

What I have found out so far is that when the cursor is on the scatter plot, the icon disappears and it works fine. I think that is because I set `hovertemplate=[]` in the scatterplot. I cannot do that in the candlestick plot because there is no such parameter for it. Moreover, this icon only appears if I set `hovermode='x unified'`. If I set it to x, the little icon doesn't appear. But I need it to be exactly like the tradingview.com example that I showed.
Is there any way to replicate that crosshair?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried `fig.update_layout(hoverdistance=0)`. But the problem is that when the cursor is not on the candlesticks, the crosshair is just not right. I took two screenshots: the first one is from tradingview.com charts and the second one is from my code with `hoverdistance` set to 0.[image][image]
As can be seen, when the cursor is not on the candlesticks, in the first screenshot the crosshair is still correct. However, in the second screenshot it is just not working correctly. It only works if the cursor is on the candlesticks ONLY. 
I just want to copy [tradingview.com](https://tradingview.com) crosshair. Nothing less and nothing more.

**UPDATE 2:**

I think the answer could be on these [plotly docs](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing). I am working on it currently. Please share your comments about this update.

Comment: just fyi, looks like `from plotly.subplots import make_subplots` is missing

Comment: why use `hovermode='x unified'`? It's [purpose](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#unified-hovermode) is to get all values in one hover label, is that what you intend?

Comment: @Amir how did `ig.update_layout(hoverdistance=0)` work out for you?

Comment: @jayveesea If I set to `x`, the problem is the same as what I mentioned in Update 1. Your solution only works if the cursor is on the candlesticks. Thanks for your try. :)

Comment: @vestland check Update 1 please.

Comment: @vestland can you give me your opinion about update 2 also? I think the only way is using callbacks. But I didn't find a way so far.

Comment: use `spikesnap='cursor'` with @vestland's solution?

Comment: @jayveesea  YES. Which one of you win the bounty.? Is there anyway to divide it? I cannot choose the winner. You did the final touch btw. I don't know :)

Comment: @vestland who deserves the bounty? :) Is there anyway to divide it?

Comment: @Amir Feel free to award the bounty to jayveesa! There is no way to divide the bounty itself. But you can give the bounty to one, and the acceptance mark to the other. And if you feel like it, and find any other useful posts from me, I dont mind the upvotes there either =)

Comment: bounty is vestland's... my comment was just a tweak to his work

Comment: OK. I give it to @vestland. Can you please update your answer. I can do it myself too but it will be on tomorrow because i'm in rush right now. I will give the bounty tomorrow.

Comment: @jayveesea Thank you so much. I cannot divide it unfortunatly. However if I find some useful answers from you to other questions, you can count on my up-vote. Thank you so much. I was running in circles for a couple of days :)

Comment: @ jayveesa and Amir. This is *exactly* the way things should around here; A good and well researched question, quick feedback and a good answer through collaboration! And not even the slightest argument over who gets what. Points to everyone =)

Comment: glad I could help, it was fun to work on :)

Comment: @vestland Can you please update your answer? I edited it but it says it takes time to get approved. Just add `spikesnap =' cursor'` in the `fig.update_xaxes` and `fig.update_yaxes`. It is currently set to `data` in both update axes. And then I approve it and give you a big fat bounty =)

Comment: @Amir Done! Thank you!

Comment: @Amir Could you tell me how you made those cool gifs?

Comment: @vestland take several consecutive screenshots and then upload your pics to https://ezgif.com/maker. It will take care of it. Save the gif and then upload it to SO.

Comment: These seems to work as expected now..i think. when i move the cursor, i see an info box with the ohlc data.   I do have a question though..is it possible to have a floating label show the x and y values of where the cross hair/line is located..much like you see in the tradeview gif you posted?

Comment: @mike01010  I don't think it is possible currently. Dash is relatively new. Sometimes you find some bugs or problems that cannot be fixed so easily. If I found something, I will notify you here.

Comment: thanks @amir. in my case, im not using dash - just the plotly library

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do it:

```
fig.update_layout(hoverdistance=0)
```

And setting `spikesnap='cursor'` for xaxes and yaxes.

These little adjustments will keep the crosshair intact and remove the little icon that has been bothering you.

From [the docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=hoverdistance):

**Plot:**

[image]

> ***hoverdistance***
>
> Sets the default distance (in pixels) to look for data
>   to add hover labels (-1 means no cutoff, 0 means no looking for data).
>   This is only a real distance for hovering on point-like objects, like
>   scatter points. For area-like objects (bars, scatter fills, etc)
>   hovering is on inside the area and off outside, but these objects will
>   not supersede hover on point-like objects in case of conflict.

**Complete code:** (but with no dash elements)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv').iloc[:60]
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, row_heights=[0.8, 0.2], vertical_spacing=0)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(open=df['AAPL.Open'], high=df['AAPL.High'], low=df['AAPL.Low'], close=df['AAPL.Close'],
                             increasing_line_color='#0384fc', decreasing_line_color='#e8482c', name='AAPL'), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=np.random.randint(20, 40, len(df)), marker_color='#fae823', name='VO', hovertemplate=[]), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'paper_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'legend_orientation': "h"},
                  legend=dict(y=1, x=0),
                  font=dict(color='#dedddc'), dragmode='pan', hovermode='x unified',
                  margin=dict(b=20, t=0, l=0, r=40))

fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False,
                 showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False, spikedash='solid')

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, rangeslider_visible=False, showticklabels=False,
                 showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False, spikedash='solid')

fig.update_layout(hoverdistance=0)

fig.update_traces(xaxis='x', hoverinfo='none')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice1, you can also use `spikethickness` to adjust the thickness of the `spikedash`

Comment: @Christos Thank you! And thanks for the info! Haven't tried that, actually.

Answer (score 9):

If you set `hovermode='x'` then you can format the [style of the spike line](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#spike-lines) like this:

```py
fig.update_xaxes(spikecolor="grey",spikethickness=1)
```

UPDATE:
`spikesnap='cursor'` will get you closer, but not working exactly for the candlestick.

```py
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, rangeslider_visible=False, showticklabels=False,
                 showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='cursor', showline=False,
                 spikecolor="grey",spikethickness=1, spikedash='solid')
fig.update_yaxes(showspikes=True, spikedash='solid',spikemode='across', 
                spikecolor="grey",spikesnap="cursor",spikethickness=1)
fig.update_layout(spikedistance=1000,hoverdistance=1000)
```

Comment: Yes. Candlesticks are the problem :) candlesticks need hovertemplate which they don't have currently. Check update 2 please. I think the answer could be there. I am working on it too.

Answer (score 4):

All the man too complex, the easiest way:

```
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
```

[Docs for hovermode is here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=hoverdistance#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.__init__) and [python reference here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-hovermode)

[image]