# How to implement a Vertical line following mouse cursor in python plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is it possible to draw vertical line on graphs which follows the mouse or which can be controlled by method calls? The motivation is that if you have multiple variables plotted on the y-axis you may want to show the vertical line on all of variables when you move mouse on any of them.

I tried to find solution to this but could not find any concrete solution.

Comment: The approach in the post [Plotly: How to only show vertical and horizontal line (crosshair) as hoverinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794582/plotly-hoverinfo-problem-when-hovermode-is-set-to-x-unified/61885469#61885469) should solve your problem as long as you're not on an old plotly version

Comment: I'm currently using plotly version 4.6.0. Is this version good enough to carry out the above implementation ?  or should i install the latest version ?